# What is the default return type of a function in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, function

What is the default return type of a function in **Swift**?

I tried to **Google** it and I was not sure on it. Could any please share their knowledge?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Default return type is `Void`

Comment: void is the Default return type

Comment: Yes in objective-c. How about swift, because we don't see void keyword? This question is asked by one of the interviewers asked when I said the same answer.

Comment: Functions without a defined return type return a special value of type Void. This is simply an empty tuple, which is written as (). You can check here officially: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaBandaru, in `Objective C` 'by default` you will get `id` not `void` as return type.

Comment: @user28434 thanks for correcting me. In Objective-C, the default return type is "id". But that is not encouraged since it is not a good practice.

Comment: Thankyou all for the responses.

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaBandaru did you find solution?

Comment: According to documents, In Objective-C, the default return type is "id" and in swift, it is an empty tuple.

Answer (score 12):

From [docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html):

> Strictly speaking, this version of the greet(person:) function does
>   still return a value, even though no return value is defined.
>   Functions without a defined return type return a special value of type
>   Void. This is simply an empty tuple, which is written as ().

```
func greet(person: String) {
    print("Hello, \(person)!")
}
greet(person: "Dave")
// Prints "Hello, Dave!"
```

Answer (score 6):

Default return type is Void. But Void is defined as typealias of empty tuple. Like this

```
public typealias Void = ()
```

You can see this if you right click on Void and go to definition. So you can also say that return type is an empty tuple. In Swift you can omit Void keyword if a function returns nothing(ie: Void). Compiler will insert it for you. So

```
func something() -> Void
```

is same as

```
func something()
```